# I'm trying to implement Binary tree using linked list in cpp, But my code is not working

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, binary-tree

I want to implement Binary tree using Linked list, to do so also I have used stack and queue using linked list

stack and queue also I have used linked list

In my code there is no syntax error, its compiling successfully but the time of running the code its saying segmentation fault

Kindly someone please find my error and fix it..

In the below code I have divided int three separate file:-
1st file is  class file (for defining all classes ie. stack, queue, tree)

2nd file is  function file where all the functions body are present which is declared in each class.

3rd file is main file.

1st file (class.h)

```
#ifndef CLASS
#define CLASS

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

                                    //tree class (start)
class Node
{
public:
    Node *lchild;
    int data;
    Node *rchild;
};

class tree
{
private:
    Node *root = NULL;
public:
    tree();
    void preorder();
};                  
                                    //tree class (end)...
                                    //queue class (start)

class Q_Node
{
public:
    Node *data;
    Q_Node *next;
};

class Queue
{
private:
    Q_Node *first, *reare;
public:
    Queue(){first = reare = new Q_Node;}
    void enqueue(Node *x);
    Node * dequeue();
    void display();
    int isEmpty();
};
                                    //tree class (end)...
                                    //stack class (start)

class S_Node
{
public:
    Node *data;
    S_Node *next;
};

class Stack
{
private:
    S_Node *top;
public:
    Stack(){top = NULL;}
    void push(Node *x);
    Node * pop();
    int isEmpty();
    
};
                                    //stack class (end)...
#endif
```

2nd file (functions.cpp)

```
#include "classes.h"


                                            //functions of queue class
void Queue::enqueue(Node *x){
    Q_Node *t;
    t = new Q_Node;
    if(!t)
        cout<<"Queue is full"<<endl;
    else{
        t->data = x;
        t->next = NULL;
        if(!first) first = t;
        if(reare) reare->next = t;
        reare = t;
    }
}

Node * Queue::dequeue(){
    Q_Node *t;
    Node *x = NULL;
    if(!first)
        cout<<"Queue is empty"<<endl;
    else{
        t = first;
        x = t->data;
        first = first->next;
        delete t;
    }
    return x;
}

int Queue::isEmpty(){
    if(first == reare)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


                                            //functions of stack class

void Stack::push(Node *x){
    S_Node *t;
    t = new S_Node;

    if(!t)
        cout<<"Stack overflow"<<endl;
    else{
        t->data = x;
        t->next = top;
        top = t;
    }
}

Node * Stack::pop(){
    Node *x = NULL;
    S_Node *t;
    if(!top){
        cout<<"Stack is empty"<<endl;
    }else{
        x = top->data;
        t = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete t;
    }
    return x;
}

int Stack::isEmpty(){
    if(top == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

                                            //functions of tree class
tree::tree(){
    int x;
    Node *t, *p;

    Queue q;

    cout<<"Enter root value"; cin>>x;

    root = new Node;
    root->data = x;
    root->lchild=root->rchild = NULL;
    q.enqueue(root);

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        p = q.dequeue();

        cout<<"Enter left child value of "<<p->data<<": "; cin>>x;
        if(x != 1){
            t = new Node;
            t->data = x;
            t->lchild = t->rchild = NULL;
            p->lchild = t;
            q.enqueue(t);
        }

        cout<<"Enter right child value of "<<p->data<<": "; cin>>x;
        if(x != 1){
            t = new Node;
            t->data = x;
            t->lchild = t->rchild = NULL;
            p->rchild = t;
            q.enqueue(t);
        }
    }
}

void tree::preorder(){
    Node *p = root;
    Stack s;
    while(p || !s.isEmpty()){

        if(p){
            cout<<p->data<<" ";
            s.push(p);
            p = p->lchild;
        }
        else{
            p = s.pop();
            p = p->rchild;
        }
    }
}
```

3rd file (main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    tree t;
    t.preorder();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `Queue` class you cannot seem to decide, if `first` is the node holding the first element or the predecessor of the node holding the first element.

`Queue::Queue` initializes `first` to a node with `data` not being initialized. `Queue::enqueue` then adds a new node after `first` and `dequeue` returns the `data` pointer in `first` which is still not initialized and therefore points to an arbitrarty address. Accessing this address has a very high chance of yielding an access violation error which is what happened in your case.

---

Btw: note that

```
Q_Node *t;
t = new Q_Node;
if(!t)
    cout<<"Queue is full"<<endl;
else ...
```

will not yield the expected result. If it isn't possible to allocate more memory `std::bad_alloc` is thrown instead of `new` returning `nullptr`. You need to use the `nothrow` variant instead for this to work:

```
#include <new>
...

Q_Node *t;
t = new(std::nothrow) Q_Node;
if(!t)
    cout<<"Queue is full"<<endl;
else ...
```